# Implement the `<=>` three-way comparison operator on numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, comparison

In C++, there exists a [`a <=> b` three-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466358/what-is-the-spaceship-three-way-comparison-operator-in-c) [comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) that, for numerical types, does the following:

- If `a < b`, then return a negative number.
- If `a = b`, then return a (mathematically speaking) sign-less number.
- If `a > b`, then return a positive number.

### The Challenge

Implement the **shortest** full program, function, method, or custom operator such that, when given two numbers of the same type `a` and `b`,

- If `a < b`, then return `-1`.
- If `a = b`, then return `0`.
- If `a > b`, then return `1`.

#### Notes

- If you're writing in x86 assembly, [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259087/) may be of use to you.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Can the input be assumed to be an Integer, or can it have a fractional component?

Comment: @ATaco It can have a fractional component; a number is a number is a number

Comment: Haskell has a builtin `compare` which solves this task with the wrong output format.  It outputs `LT`, `GT` or `EQ`. `hgl` implements this as `cp`.

Comment: Ruby has the same operator

Comment: Do we have to handle all combinations of inputs?  (I.e. can we assume that `a - b` will yield the arithmetic result, even when `a` is the lowest representable value and `b` is the highest?)

Comment: @TobySpeight You will need to handle all combinations of inputs.

Comment: Note that the C++ 3-way comparison is actually "compares equal to 0" and "compares less than 0" and "compares greater than 0".   1 and -1 are explicitly not required, by design, unlike your ask.  I only mention this because your first paragraphs are not true.

Comment: @Yakk Correct ([C++ doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison)). Same behavior in java.lang.Comparable.compareTo() too. This golf challenge is not faithful to the actual behavior in programming languages.

Comment: If a language has support for multiple numeric types, such as integers and floating point numbers, does it need to support all of them? Basically every solution using subtraction and supporting floating point numbers doesn't work.

Comment: @Tyilo the original draft of this challenge in sandbox had a bonus for supporting multiple numeric types, but was cut because "bonuses are bad". Pick whichever numeric type leads to the shortest solution.

Answer (score 8):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 2 bytes

```
×-
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=R3RsdCDihpAgw5ctCkd0bHTCtMKoIOKfqCAz4oC/NiwgM+KAvzMsIDbigL8zIOKfqQ==)

```
×       # sign of
 -      # left arg minus right arg
```

---

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes

```
<->
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=R3RsdCDihpAgPC0+Ckd0bHTCtMKoIOKfqCAz4oC/NiwgM+KAvzMsIDbigL8zIOKfqQ==)

This clearly isn't the shortest possible solution in [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/) (see above), but it is particularly visually appealing due to its similarity to the C++/Perl/etc `<=>` operator.

```
<->     # 3-element train abc 
        # ( x abc y expands to: (x a y) b (x c y) )
<       # left arg < right arg
 -      # minus
  >     # left arg > right arg
```

(a similar 'reverse-comparison' operator - [`>-<`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=THRndCDihpAgPi08Ckx0Z3TCtMKoIOKfqCAz4oC/NiwgM+KAvzMsIDbigL8zIOKfqQ==) is also possible and also [I think] looks nice)

Comment: Polyglots with Dyalog APL too

Comment: Does this handle overflows?

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yes and yes.  The [first one](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=R3RsdCDihpAgw5ctCkd0bHTCtMKoIOKfqCAz4oC/MWUxMDAwLCAz4oC/MywgMWUxMDAw4oC/MyDin6kgIyAxZTEwMDAgb3ZlcmZsb3dzIGFuZCBpcyByZXByZXNlbnRlZCBhcyBpbmZpbml0eQo=) is helped by BQN's representation of overflowing-numbers as infinity (type 1e1000 into the REPL to see); the [second one](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=R3RsdCDihpAgPC0+Ckd0bHTCtMKoIOKfqCAz4oC/MWUxMDAwLCAz4oC/MywgMWUxMDAw4oC/MyDin6k=) only needs to compare two booleans so doesn't have a problem.

Comment: Isn't what you call "reverse-comparison" operator actually the correct answer to this question, and not the other one?

Comment: @wimi - Hm - I think you're right (that ```>-<``` and not ```<->``` is equivalent to ```<=>```).  The question itself just states that we are 'given two numbers', without specifying the order, but I agree that they're the wrong way around...  That's a pity

Answer (score 8):

## polyglot, 3 bytes

```perl
<=>
```

[Try it in Perl!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1CUmVeiYPzfxtbuv5k1hKcUk6dkzQWVUQDKKBhjkTHDlPkPAA)

<Insert [other languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison#High-level_languages) that already have the exact `<=>` operator here>

Comment: is this valid? it's not a function, after all...

Comment: I don't know, really.  The challenge reads "Implement the shortest full program, function, method, or custom operator...".  It's an operator.  Obviously it isn't custom, because it's a built-in, and for the same reason I didn't implement it myself, but otherwise it seems Ok...

Comment: ah, didn't see the part about custom operators being explicitly allowed... but yeah it does still feel on the line

Comment: I'm not sure, since the OP speaks of C++, where you can define custom operators, and asks us to *implement* it.. simply inserting the operator you chose in an answer would not do, the code should implement it

Comment: @Kaddath - I agree with you, but currently I count at least 8 built-in answers (Python 2, Java, 05AB1E, etc) that don't implement anything.  That's why I feel it's appropriate to put all the boring built-ins together into a 'community wiki' answer...

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 3 bytes

```python
cmp
```

A built-in function that accepts \$a\$ and \$b\$ and returns \$a \lt = \gt b\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPzm34H9BUWZeiUaahqmOgrmm5n8A)**

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 17 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>(a>b)-(a<b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1k4j0S5JU1cj0SZJ839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahpGmhrGmJheGoBGGoDFY8D8A)

Comment: 3 bytes can be cut down by using `Math.sign(a-b)`

Comment: @cmd We would still need to take `a` and `b` as input, for a total of +3 bytes. (If we had a `Math.cmp` builtin taking 2 arguments, then the answer would be just `Math.cmp`.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(a>b)-(a<b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKI9EuSVNXI9EmSfN/QVFmXolGmoahjpGmJheCZ4jEMwLx/gMA)

Python 3 lacks the builtin `cmp`

-1 thanks to Dominic van Essen

Comment: Surely ```lambda a,b:(a>b)-(a<b)``` is only 22...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Of course!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
-±
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCItwrEiLCIiLCI2XG44Il0=)

Takes input as b then a. Simply subtract the two numbers and get the sign of the result.

Alternatively a more fun looking, symbol only answer comes in at 17 bytes:

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 17 bytes

```
-:::-<[::-$~-|:]/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCItOjo6LTxbOjotJH4tfDpdLyIsIiIsIjEwXG4xMiJd)

Also takes b then a. This answer is purely just for fun, and could be made shorter by using numbers and letters (`-D0<[N|:]/`).

#### Explained

```
-:::-<[::-$~-|:]/
-:                # Subtract the two numbers and push a copy
  ::-             # Push 0 to the stack by subtracting the top of the stack from itself
     <            # Is the original top of the stack < 0?
      [           # If so:
       ::         #   Duplicate the top of the stack twice. This could just be `D`, but that wouldn't be a symbol.
         -        #   Subtract those copies to get 0 again.
          $~-     #   Push the 0 under the top of the stack, and subtract without popping. The stack is now [0, a - b, -(a - b)]
             |    # Otherwise:
              :   #   Just duplicate the top of the stack
               ]  # this whole if statement was to make sure there was [a - b, abs(a - b)] as the stack
                / # Divide the top two stack items to get either -1, 0 or 1. negative/positive = -1, 0/0 = 0 and positive/positive = 1
```

Comment: `-:ȧ/` or `₌><-` for a non builtin

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 14 bytes

```java
Float::compare
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY4xC8IwEIVn8ysytlCDxUFo1UVwc@ooDmdtSmrShORakNLfHmMoOOpNd@9973EdjLDuHk8vlNEWaRduNqCQ7KSVAQuobUnMcJeiprUE5@gFRE8nQsM4BAz6F92fpQY8Un7wcSuKOnqNL2NgKVpyoxYPqkJdUqEVfXu9UbCtSyeyql4OG8X0gMwEC2WfcLZ0JTnPcp6m5W9s@w@24dkucp8PZzL7Nw)

### [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 13 bytes

```java
Long::compare
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY49D4IwEIZn@ys6QoKNxMEE1MW1TozG4UQgRfqR9iAxhN9eCyFx1Jvu7n3uybUwwLZ9vryQRlukbZhZj6JjFy0NWEBtc2L6RydKWnbgHL2CUHQkNJRDwLD/okeuVXOm9cnPTZaVS1L5fMFXzXo1aPGkMsiiAq1Qze1OwTYuHsmmeDusJNM9MhMi7FRUs9UVpTxJeRznv7H9P9iOJ4eFmz@cyOQ/)

Only supports integers.

Comment: For a more general solution: `Comparable::compareTo` (not golfier but felt like sticking this in a comment)

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the question. [`Float.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-) returns a positive, zero, or negative number to indicate ordering, not +1, 0, -1. The problem is that the question is more restrictive than what programming languages actually prescribe.

Comment: @Nayuki Did you try testing the code through the [TIO link](https://tio.run/##jY4xC8IwEIVn8ysytlCDxUFo1UVwc@ooDmdtSmrShORakNLfHmMoOOpNd@9973EdjLDuHk8vlNEWaRduNqCQ7KSVAQuobUnMcJeiprUE5@gFRE8nQsM4BAz6F92fpQY8Un7wcSuKOnqNL2NgKVpyoxYPqkJdUqEVfXu9UbCtSyeyql4OG8X0gMwEC2WfcLZ0JTnPcp6m5W9s@w@24dkucp8PZzL7Nw) in my answer? It never returns anything other than -1, 0, or 1. On Code Golf, ["a programming language is defined by its implementation"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/99986). My code works on this implementation (always giving the correct outputs), so it is a valid submission.

Comment: Most implementations do return -1, 0, or 1 for the static `compare` methods. (In fact, it'd be strange to have an implementation not return one of those, as that doesn't make it any easier to implement.) For example, you can see OpenJDK's source for Float here: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Float.java#L875

Comment: @Unmitigated You are relying on an implementation detail that is not covered by the documentation. It is subject to change at any time without notice.

Comment: "Most implementations do return -1, 0, or 1 for the static `compare` methods": And some don't. For narrow types like `byte`, the easiest legal implementation of `compare()` is to subtract: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/Byte.java#L438-L440

Comment: @Nayuki That doesn't matter. The consensus is that languages are defined by implementation, not specification. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/whats-the-policy-on-interpreter-bugs/7833#7833, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/99986. So it's perfectly valid to rely on undefined or implementation-dependent behavior. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/is-an-answer-allowed-to-use-undefined-but-consistent-behaviour as well as the comments there.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
*@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqCjYKBgBcS6egrOQT5u/7UcdP9rcqUmZ@QrGCukKZghmMYIpgGUqWcCEtcz/Q8A) The 3-byte solution `>-<` featured in a few other answers also works for the same byte count (greater-than minus less-than).

Works for any numeric type. Anonymous dyad.

### Explanation

```
*@-
*     sign
 @    of
  -   difference
```

Comment: Looks like a dyad to me.

Comment: @south Right you are! Heavens know why I said monad lol

Comment: Outputs the wrong answer for `(-1e308, -1e308) => _1` and `(-1e308, 1e308) => 0`

Comment: @Tyilo OP clarified that we can pick whichever type works for the golf. The numbers you provided are floating point numbers. I pick the integer type, which you will note my solution works well for. If you insist on numbers so large, you can use the extended type: `(-10^308x) f (-10^308x)` outputs `0` as expected.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Then you probably shouldn't list `echo 3.4 f 3.5` as an example input in your TIO link ;)

Comment: @Tyilo I suppose, fair enough! Just shows it works so long as the input isn't deviously crafted :)

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 12 bytes

```
=SIGN(A1-B1)
```

where `A1` and `B1` contain *a* and *b* respectively.

Comment: This does not appear to handle overflows

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes (3 nibbles)

```
`$-
```

```
`$-         # full program
`$-$@       # with implicit args shown;
`$          # get sign of
   $        # arg1
  -         # minus
    @       # arg2
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
1&-_1^-%-
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLszJU0403jNNV1eXiSos2tDaIBVK6JtaGINrY2hhEGejBxCEsAFB/DI8=)

K lacks a sign builtin, which makes this a bit trickier.

`-%-` negative square root of a-b. This is negative if a>b, zero if a=b and `-0n` (negative null value) if a<b.
`1^` Replace null with 1.
`-_` floor and negate the number. In combination with the earlier `-` this does a ceil on the square root.
`1&` take the minimum of 1 and this number.

If the input was restricted to integers, `0 1'` would calculate the sign, leading to `0 1'-` as a full solution.

Comment: If the input was restricted to integers, you could also do `1&-1|-`...

Answer (score 4):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```go
func(a,b int)int{n:=1
for-1<n&&b-a<n{n--}
return-n}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBisIwEIbZa55i9CAJZMSwFESsdw-Cl70uxGKkaKcSUxGKT-KlCPtQ7tNssqlY9ZAM8__z_RlyuW7K5tbb62yrN2sodE4sL_aldcO-KVyfHbUFA-lP5QyOb5-mooxruYKcnPCnpkmqmCktqikNBivUU6oJ8czs2lWWkM4R_f0Qgf1_gQuo2dJ6fEfccCUTITp9ItVL_-yjkviiJBLVmxJmWFbSwcFCn768BVW4UvgOlY8E3O2cuvYIHtjcK1ENyD1nNgPVpR9T2DIIinX2iTOyTXxaNUqyjfFW-2NNE-sf)

By @Kevin Cruijssen. Uses a `for` loop to get the return value rather than a chain of `if`s.

#### Changelog

- -1 by @naffetS

#### Old answer, 56 bytes

```go
func(a,b int)int{n:=0
if a>b{n=1}
if a<b{n=-1}
return n}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVC9asMwEKarnuLqSQKpWIMhlNh7h0KXrgXZREYkPgdFLgXjJ-liCn0o92kqRTZxkkG6u-9Ph75_6nacHo-q2qt6B40ySExzbK17SnTjEvKpLGjIfzunxWba6A4rqngJBh3zp8fnPCVGgyrKHnM5nPtt6IUf7M51FgGH6P97YCHg_Axl0JM36zMOSDWVPGNsNWdc3szXvJBc3CAZF_IOCRpStXhy8Kq-3j0FXbhy-AiVpgwW2uCaTuFie_FIRINlySkKkGv3RSVmjwBJVvtEDZ8Tr1aNEJ9jPDX_2DjG-g8)

Go doesn't have any sort of built-in `abs` like C, or default type methods like Java, so a function it is. Go also doesn't have ternary expressions, so the old-school "set and check" pattern is needed.

Comment: Wow, this seems really long!  I don't speak GO, but can't you at least save a few bytes [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVC9asMwEKarnuLiSQKpWIOhhNp7hkCXrgXFWEE0PhtVDgXjJ-liCn0o92kqRTZx0kG6u-9Ph76-j804bVpVvqtjBbUySEzdNtY9Jrp2CTkrCxryn85p8TRtdYclVfwABh3zp8dtrsSBGA1YpD3mcrj0z6EXfrCV6ywCDjHh94GFiMtDlEFPXqxPOSHVVPKMsdWccXk33_JCcnGHZFzIf0jQkLLBDwd79fnqKejClcNbqDRlsNAG13QKV9vOIxENliWnKECu3VeVmD0CJFntEzV8TrxZNUJ8jvHU_GPjGOsf)?

Comment: Or even [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVC9asMwEKarnuLqSQKpWIMhlNh7h0KXrgXZREYkPgdFLgXjJ-liCn0o92kqRTZxkkG6u-9Ph75_6nacHo-q2qt6B40ySExzbK17SnTjEvKpLGjIfzunxWba6A4rqngJBh3zp8fnPCVGgyrKHnM5nPtt6IUf7M51FgGH6P97YCHg_Axl0JM36zMOSDWVPGNsNWdc3szXvJBc3CAZF_IOCRpStXhy8Kq-3j0FXbhy-AiVpgwW2uCaTuFie_FIRINlySkKkGv3RSVmjwBJVvtEDZ8Tr1aNEJ9jPDX_2DjG-g8)...?

Comment: Yeah, the else was real obvious and somehow I missed that lol.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBqsIwEEVxm68YXUiCiRiwIGK7dyG4cfsgFiNFO5WYilD8Ejflwfso39eYmIpVF8kw9865GXL93Rb1rXtQ6U5tN5CrDEmWHwpjhz2d2x45KQMa4r_SajG5jXWJKVV8DRla5k6F01hIogsDSqwT7PdxJiscDC7EbGxpEPAS2P8O8_DjCcqgIkvj-D1STSWPGGv1EZcf_bsvJBcfSsSF_FL8DEkLPFpYqPPKWVD6K4YfX-mIwdPOsG2P4IXNnRJUjzxzkgRkm35NiYYRIElrnzDDm8S3VYPEmxhnNT9W16HeAQ)

Comment: [-1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBisIwEIbZa55i9CAJZMSwFESsdw-Cl70uxGKkaKcSUxGKT-KlCPtQ7tNssqlY9ZAM8__z_RlyuW7K5tbb62yrN2sodE4sL_aldcO-KVyfHbUFA-lP5QyOb5-mooxruYKcnPCnpkmqmCktqikNBivUU6oJ8czs2lWWkM4R_f0Qgf1_gQuo2dJ6fEfccCUTITp9ItVL_-yjkviiJBLVmxJmWFbSwcFCn768BVW4UvgOlY8E3O2cuvYIHtjcK1ENyD1nNgPVpR9T2DIIinX2iTOyTXxaNUqyjfFW-2NNE-sf)

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 8 bytes

```
+(*cmp*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfW0MrObdAS/O/tUJxYqWCkkq8gq2dQnWaQo1KfK2SQlp@kYKNoYGCkZ2Ogo2RgqEBiAbygYz/AA)

`cmp` is Raku's built-in smart comparison operator, and `*cmp*` is an anonymous function that passes its arguments to that operator.

Unfortunately for this challenge, `cmp` doesn't return -1, 1, or 0, but one of the enumerated values `Less`, `More`, or `Same`, so the prefix `+` operator converts those values into their integer values.

The non-golfy solution would be to just compose the two operators:

```
&prefix:<+> o &[cmp]
```

Comment: can use [`cmp`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/cmp.html) to not write the space

Comment: @MustafaAydın Huh!  I assumed `cmp` was the stringwise version of `<=>` as in Perl 5, but it's smarter than that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### HP‑41C series,  <s>9</s>  11 Bytes

`a` needs to be entered first, then `b`, so `a` is placed in the Y register and `b` in the X register.

```
01♦LBL⸆S     5 Bytes    global label requires 4 + m Bytes
02 SF 24     2 Bytes    ignore “out of range” errors, and instead
                        return ±9.999999999E99 as an approximation
03 −         1 Byte     X ≔ Y − X
04 X≠0?      1 Byte     if X = 0 then skip next line
05 SIGN      1 Byte     ↯ `SIGN` returns `1` for zero
06 RTN       1 Byte     `RTN` does not affect local label search
```

Comment: Does work also on the Free42 calculator

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 16 bytes

```
Float::compareTo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6FZzVWWmKOQZqXglpOfWKKnAaY0FXTtFDzzShRsFf6DBayskvNzCxKLUkPy/1sXFGXmleTkaaRpGKbpKBilaWpyoQoZYgoZgIRq/wMA)

Annoyingly, longer than Java.

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 14 bytes

```
Int::compareTo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6FZzVWWmKOQZqXgmVeipwEkNBV07UAcBVuF/0DKyio5P7cgsSg1JP@/dUFRZl5JTp5GmoahjoKRpiYXioAhuoABUKD2PwA)

Works only on ints (I edited this after seeing that Java got edited).

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 15 bytes

```r
\(a,b)sign(a-b)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhbrYzQSdZI0izPT8zQSdZM0IaJb0jQMdYw0uUCUIYgyAlIQqQULIDQA)

Comment: It would have been [cooler](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGKBFUbWzvVBNulpSVpuhbrYzQSdZI0izPT8zQSdZM0IaJ7jRXAqhTMuGAsYy4zGAuiZsECCA0A) if you'd made it inline as ```%<=>%```, though...

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.S
```

Builtin. Takes the inputs in the order \$b,a\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fL/j/fyMuUwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
.S  # Compare the second (implicit) input-integer `a` with the first (implicit)
    # input-integer `b`, and push -1 if a<b; 0 if a==b; or 1 if a>b
    # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
.~>\~<-
```

read from stdin

```
# explanation:
. # duplicate
~ # unpack
> # gt 
\ # store the result and get duplicated stdin again
~ # unpack
< # lt
- # gt-lt
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 2 bytes

```
cm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dkPo/Ofd/bXjOf0MFQwMDAy4QoWDIBeQBAA)

Built in compare.

Answer (score 3):

## PIC16F88x Machine Code, 6 words (84 bits)

A function that expects `a` to be at address 0x70 in memory, and `b` to be in register W. Returns the result in register W.

The PIC16 uses 14-bit instruction words. Because the number of words is even, this function can be represented exactly in hex with no padding:

```
0bc1d03d001ff0dfff401
```

In mpasm syntax, that is:

```
    SUBWF 0x70,F   ; Subtract W from the value at 0x70. Leave the result at
                   ; 0x70.
    BTFSC STATUS,2 ; Check the zero flag (bit 2 of the STATUS register) and skip
                   ; the next instruction if it's not set.
    RETLW 0x00     ; Set the W register to 0 and return.
    BTFSC 0x70,7   ; Skip the next instruction if the MSb of the value at 0x70
                   ; is 0 (i.e. the result of subtraction is positive).
    RETLW 0xFF     ; Set the W register to 0xff (-1) and return.
    RETLW 0x01     ; Set the W register to 1 and return.
```

Bit for bit, this is encoded as:

```
00 0010 1111 0000
00 0010           SUBWF
         111 0000       0x70
        1                    F

01 1101 0000 0011
01 11             BTFSC
         000 0011       STATUS
     01 0                      2

11 0100 0000 0000
11 01             RETLW
        0000 0000       0x00
     00                      (ignored)

01 1111 1111 0000
01 11             BTFSC
         111 0000       0x70
     11 1                    7

11 0111 1111 1111
11 01             RETLW
        1111 1111       0xff
     11                      (ignored)

11 0100 0000 0001
11 01             RETLW
        0000 0001       0x01
     00                      (ignored)
```

The PIC16F88x family of microcontrollers have four memory banks of 128 bytes each. (These are actually bytes this time, and not 14-bit words.) Which one is used depends on the value of the STATUS register. However, addresses 0x70 through 0x7f are the same on all banks, so by placing the operands there the function doesn't have to change banks to access them. I'm not aware of any standard calling convention as far as argument location goes, but the return value being in register W is standard (hence the existence of the `RETLW` instruction).

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
-/<?,
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxNikEOgjAQRfc9xSxcaOJQRFlITbyEO0JCxUEI0GJbIsTo2a1EE5P5mf/yX5kgPxzXjJ2SxyKdXiYpIYBR5LoRy7yUdStGMQmzyp7eSQFgAxAK/7IZceerAPwibP35NZwxDP5l/OFHZpxVzvU24bzQF7rqtgysk0VDY1FJdaWg0B2/DWRdrZXlUbyP4pjXXd9SR8qhq8jHEOFdTujlXpraaoW6JyOdNui7GrozGcvecr9DqA==)

- `,` concatenate the inputs
- `<?` grade-up the distinct-ified result from above; if the first value is smaller than the second, the result will be `0 1`; if larger, `1 0`, if the same, `,0`
- `-/` run a minus-reduce and (implicitly) return

An alternative version that takes the input as a list of two numbers is `-/<?:`.

Comment: Aah, how did I miss this? Only had the APLcart version (`{⊃(⍋-⍒)⍺⍵}`) in mind, which would've been too long because of the two grades

Answer (score 2):

### Pascal, 55 Bytes

```pascal
function f(a,b:real):real;begin f:=ord(a>b)-ord(a<b)end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 29 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(1*) \1
0
1+0
1
01+
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0vDUEtTIcaQy4DLUBuIuQwMtbl0Df//N1Yw5zJVMOUyVzAGAA) Link includes test cases. Only works on non-negative integers. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(1*) \1
0
```

Try to subtract; this will leave `0` if `a = b`.

```
1+0
1
```

If `a > b` then replace the result with `1`.

```
01+
-1
```

If `a < b` then replace the result with `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＩ⁻›θη‹θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ8B5AcUZeaVaDgnFpdo@GbmlRZruBelJpaAFOsoZGjqKPikFhdD2EBg/f@/sYL5f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.

Alternative approach, also 12 bytes:

```
≔⁻ＮＮθＩ÷θ∨↔θ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DNzOvtFjDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0cBhQvkF2pacwUUZeaVaDgnFpcAVZe4ZJZlpqRqFOoo@BdpOCYV5@eUlgC5QLWGmkBg/f@/sYL5f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Divides the difference between the numbers by the absolute value of the difference, or `1` if that's zero.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
,σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/nfPP//0YKplymYGwEAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
,  # Subtract the second (implicit) input by the first (implicit) input: b-a
 σ # Get the sign of that (-1 if <0; 0 if ==0; 1 if >0)
   # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

This is practically @TobySpeight's answer now since he changed the entire algorithm.

```c
f(a,b){a=(a>b)-(a<b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xCoRADEV7T/ERlAQypWzh6klskhHFYodl1048@xhFTJEi/738GOYYc55IxXjTjrQ3DqRv43bPH10ScbEVuGdJK1Rg7XP5R00TldWIaiwFtae1u0/@/blzAeIEQu97SE6ebwRnMYxd2HOD1wE)

Comment: The more usual implementation, [`a=(a>b)-(a<b)`](https://tio.run/##PY4xDsIwDEX3nMIqahVLCRtiaMlJujgJhUjgIlq6VD17cBCqBw9@73852FsIOQ@ajMeVLpqcR6up89hu@ZA4PD7xCt00xzQe704lnuFJifUypohqVfCfAsiAb/fLFIgHXdUR6lgZaIQ2Urvz11syP8GIAdbJ7lnMUmOg/AQeJbDlE5y/) is not only 4 bytes shorter, but also correct for values where `a-=b` is undefined due to signed integer overflow.

Comment: @TobySpeight I didn't think of that ... thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
._-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy9e10jB5P9/AA)

Defines a function which takes two inputs b, a.

#### Explanation

```
  -    # subtract the second argument from the first
._     # take the sign
```

Comment: It makes an emoticon :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
aCMb
```

There's a built-in operator for that. (Fun fact: in my original designs for Pip, this operator was `<=>`, until I realized that having a 3-character operator in a golfing language was silly.)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZLEp19kyBMqMjKaGMdBWM9Q5NYqAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>13</s> 3 bytes

```julia
cmp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/Obfgv0NxRn65QpqeRrSJjqmOWaxOtCmQNo3V/A8A)

-10 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use `cmp`

### Alternate solution, 13 bytes

```julia
a%b=sign(a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P1E1ybY4Mz1PI1E3SfO/Q3FGfrlCtImOqY5ZrIKeqkK0KZBpGvsfAA)

### Alternate solution (15 bytes)

```julia
a%b=(a>b)-(a<b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P1E1yVYj0S5JU1cj0SZJ879DcUZ@uUK0iY6pjlmsgp6qQrQpkGka@x8A)

Some operators have lower precedence than `<` and `>`. Redefining one of them as `-` removes the need for parentheses but doesn't save bytes overall:

```julia
~=-
a%b=a>b~a<b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v85WlytRNck20S6pLtEm6b9DcUZ@uUK0iY6pjlmsgp6qQrQpkGka@x8A)

Comment: 3 bytes : `cmp`

Comment: Good catch! I've added your solution here, but it probably deserves its own answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 21 bytes (4×7=28 codels)

```
vekabrA krbtkFbks?Tbb
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxVisEKwjAQRH9F5jyBbFq0ya8kOUiNUKhpIXoS_92NXnQZ2Nn39ol5uxSEGIVyoqccKSOd7swoXonrwHY1dDRqGyiTItXiv6zH_yZnopUdAcYYEOty0y5WR6_SZoTreW2FWOr-uH_cwdlU9T1V99_F4vUGIvQocg)

[image]

Just a minor variation from [my answer to "output the sign"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246527/78410). Takes two numbers and subtracts instead of taking just one number, and then the rest follows the same logic.

```
A1->A4
inN inN -    [a-b] Take two numbers and subtract
A4->A7->B7->B5
dup 1 ! > !  [a-b a-b<=0]
CC+          [a-b] Continue on row B if a-b<=0, shift to row C otherwise
B5->B2
! 1 -        [(a-b==0)-1] -1 if a-b!=0 (which implies a-b<0), 0 otherwise
C5->C2
1            [a-b 1] Ignore the previous number and push 1
C2->C1
outN         Print the top number and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## AArch64 machine code, 16 bytes

AArch64's conditional select instructions get their time to shine.

```
0000000000000000 <spaceship>:
   0:   eb01001f    cmp x0, x1
   4:   9a9f07e0    cset x0, ne
   8:   da80a400    cneg x0, x0, lt
   c:   d65f03c0    ret
```

`cset` sets the destination register to 1 or 0 according to whether the condition code is true or false.  (Fun fact: it's actually an alias for `csinc x0, xzr, xzr, eq`, where `csinc X, Y, Z, cond` sets X to Y if the condition is true, and to Z+1 if false.)

`cneg X, Y, cond` sets X either to -Y or Y according to whether the condition is true or false.  (Alias for `csneg X, Y, Y, cond`.)

Several other permutations are also possible, such as

```
cset x0, gt              // x0 = (a > b) ? 1 : 0
csinv x0, x0, xzr, lt    // x0 = (a < b) ? x0 : ~0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 45 bytes

```
load"a,b=...return a>b and 1or a<b and-1or 0"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/bDoIwDH33KxqeII5lZVy2RHz0zY8oAZSEi1kg4e8RUHAa99Cdnva0PfVAU5lOdUe5QyxLOeem6AfTAp0zoDYH7AzQacX@goUzXWm8zIoeUkCe6CTWEmWo4kBipIqjFOpweJiq7d3Sbai/86Zq56y4FYbBi6DxTXje3upvcxlsyK4G8wrNwI@TQFo8CiEYLJGL9aEt0qjCaBatv1XQKomjUC4SZGBlX3IM5Draoj43@n@O/DG3ud3te970BA)

Lua has a strict type system, and there is no shorter way than `a and 1or 0` to convert a boolean to an integer.

This version works for all comparable types (e.g. integer, floating point, and string).

## Lua, 35 bytes

```
load"a,b=...return-1+2/(0^(a-b)+1)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9LDoIwEN1zioYVDW3ttHzaBVt3XsGkRFASQNOUhNsjoGA1zmI@b@bNzGsHM9XF1N7NJTSkLBhjtnKD7SnE4hDxc2RoiWPA4XQy43Gec6hAwHKdZ1qCTFQmJKSqiiVXQfCwTe@iOuqMu7Gu6eequlaWoBdgxjeA8T5Kt70EbZnfFfMJTRDNciE9HDjnBC2e8dXAJ2lQSTqT1ug1tMqzNJELBQjyqi86CLmu9qDPj/TPkz/iNrW7fIynJw)

This is based on my answer to [Output the sign](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220076/17216). It gives the correct result for all floating point inputs, and most integer inputs.

It [doesn't meet the requirements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259255/implement-the-three-way-comparison-operator-on-numbers?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#comment571652_259255) of this challenge for integer inputs, as it will fail when passed, for example, `math.maxinteger` and `math.mininteger` (as demonstrated in the test harness), because subtracting one from the other results in an overflow. But it does fully work for all floating point inputs, thus [meeting the challenge's requirements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259255/implement-the-three-way-comparison-operator-on-numbers?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#comment571776_259255) for that type.

Comment: You can save six bytes by taking in program arguments and printing out the answer instead of using the load function [like this](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/USfJVk9Pr6AoM69EI9EuSSExL0XBML9IIdEGzNYFsQ00////r2v43xAA)

Comment: @bluswimmer Thanks, but I chose a function because it's a more elegant form of presentation, takes its input in an actual type instead of as strings, and can easily process more than one input in the test harness. I don't know if it's even possible to make a TIO or ATO test harness in Lua that demonstrates more than one input with a full program. So you could consider my choice of language is "Lua function", which means that a full program wouldn't beat it, since it wouldn't be in the same language.

Comment: @bluswimmer Case in point: The TIO you gave me is comparing the input [as strings, not numbers](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/USfJVk9Pr6AoM69EI9EuSSExL0XBML9IIdEGzNYFsQ00////b2T839DIGAA "Lua – Try It Online"). Without yet having tried it yet, I'm guessing a full program to compare numbers will actually be longer due to the need to convert the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```hs
a#b|a<b= -1|a>b=1|0<1=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZp2CrkJLPpaBQUJSZV6KgomCgoKxgiMQ3ROMbgflcGsqaClZWCv5FKQqJCrZ2QEIXSnjmlfxPVE6qSbRJslXQNaxJtEuyNawxsDG0Nfj/HwA)

-1, thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)!

The 'nicer' solution of `((pred.fromEnum).).compare` is 26 bytes.

Comment: `True` -> `0<1` for -1

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 5 bytes

```
Order
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7378oJbXof0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXUhpQU5qcXRQYl56qoOljlHsfwA)

Input `Order[b, a]`. Works on any atomic numbers.

Note the reversed order of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 19 bytes

```powershell
[math]::Sign($a-$b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqijkmRrpmP6Pzo3sSQj1soqODM9T0MlUVclSfP/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf), 18 bytes

```
TiiT*+1+,:1+s,T+__
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=3VjJkts2EK3KIQflmB9AOAeTFsWI8jbR1EyVE2df7CSTVZlSYUhIwpgiGQCUR_6VXHyJPyCf469JN7iLIMd25RSWqkQS3a_3RhN_vUz3apPEL1698x7fpolQRO7lqLilYp1SIdlopP8EOa1eeQ_FOtuyWD3RK3bIZCB4qngSn1pbHvN1Eq0sZ3REclaPhuGSFjz2rRWP2C0XVvsutU8ZiJNKOKX0A4jJDgBMrDRALYDZkioRbKlExiwz6YZFKRI-ETxWpFSb7JiQCGGvEkGCDQue8nhNHp4_JlkaUsWkY_VqFfx3Wj3OVJopEnGpSLIiQRKyNAFFJaHwQ9-AWqgJiJfAUCik_1AlacMaX2HMpLeba1kpWmpbu6l3BzjxDbvmyp4CJeKjWMsa_Z2p1eT4n3POz2-P_bE798fSPR8vl_nCq_ffRSqpaPAUOBYXICYGVWX1gHc2ZJInVchjTzAa2s7Y-iO2HE-mEUjU9yN0MCc8hp9czCf-Ra4lKB2x2OYOOSPTeeWkIBOYg2xHI1irXgM1pouNyw451Vkzb3k2186jacri0EaH2lua2okIXQ3qODUaiyQb4tb0DYM1Wv5UvV7y8BqWpqNRyFZ5XGx071wnNJmcaa5cimAyi1TuOXzWLgmv3dwvLIbEEpBzmt-ZN43maKt1Ys3JEdCFS-Bs6a3YNq1xy-vZBmqvkLoAj5MPAMS15p1ULNlzUi9NUtu5IGP9vkUcAVWTqLVYLBTOW0QlwoHDwYREbZgY4C0iLpjKRFys5Q5eRVQpyBfqDLgUvUnnnaThOmPqcLRlk_Fphc6HcuR1Vd0tZbatFFViX8MU1Pl6UZoBS1WHospfDeZSSF6NLTJwAdihCVyCzWZWCKo90LTT4AOIAyCTKEnaMYZcI3zhz9u5pHSG6D7QG_puBpZigdvB7GsKZjTYdDNRixE0XjPbh8KADgavxj4a3qRDK-MlBZlgKVB0cxpdxN2cyOmutoLYMOtATr5SkOVMDQoWVbU517UZZmk_u37AOjQjSI0gn1EDBHK55e3soowE3rs1hRH2tobdZhH5sMxvY4hq7ZoZojsotDEja8fCsn6a_jxwqNasKXBmEKgDj1J3LIAtlD9nHbnUJZfthHR7s1MHvJuceFXVctnNIM1W1TlkIie3CXW62O0k6Ric9zxEqOyigHQ5jIMCGwYBQ49XG7Ee61jDmAKxhn7xNnE-ZOvolbe1_2OEYbuibxPcYZZmDMfE3GkaIYx1CHHygCETlcc2STjsoxDTWX9zic1wXMMJ9mfGYLSM2bUidrAPIh44-bDTQoSdWZA0kxsy8fXYgRSESwK7uNp7h_mkB7d8HEJh0xs8MfGd13DeOkouaUTq6eqmMkG6RU1-0Q1hY1KDTd7vrq-aJJiqtWHmpDmc_QyeP9WeL9MbvyogCBTm4f1QWfbXyhyaBqxc1hUjO6pVDHk1P-cpUc8S_SSJStasM3fh9caFxsrp3-BIbQw1GVF2GNDKMzpVV6pLrrBYgchGvXr8X6hRzZpX4CND4KveW7uxX_JAjzgQl-8FYCE97H14HY4MN-4HZWTfbD84Pb1hQwBzrKk_u3P33v0Hxx_pbNSlDSqlkEJ8x0jI11z19xRtZ-t7qQJ--PEnjz797PMvNKw_hbD6D_qBgGDc4PFWXE_ORuQvv_r6m2-_e_zk-x9-PNfoE38G8BO_Hx4pxgecvTKwNn_SwFPvXj8mLBpZf9ass3v3-1lh0cj6S-Gs6ZCjpkbWXwvW2d0h3tldI_NvOfPseIB3dmxk_b1UeVhnPFPAebv-_PUESyMaMNtKLBem4yPpxnLpnliHBVgTLpFwejIeD9AcIY3rnwCN0zjxCPRHZX6Gkp-VSLISydZwoJJ_rRk-GLVNr__RWK0vpu2WfQafYo-6nREk4ndcMSFD4Xc70XX_AKN7Iu_ZiwpNrno0bYnoHIwEG-FeOYahFi_zDt0BAwyQbtgoSgI8AfKuwP9aZES3lyElydwqXiaw4Vwf6mCWXUM2ANEGcOjgyY5oKlu2hfJYS4xGxWlZS1FIJVeTAHR-HPbipT-aQMLnT_8C) (Since minigolf is not properly added to ATO yet, I'm using a Python runner here.)

### Explanation

We use `-1` as the base of our output. If `a-b >= 0`, we increment `-1` `a-b+1` times. However, if our output reaches `2`, we decrement it back to `1`.

````
T                 0, Base our signum output on -1 _
iiT*+             0, a + b * -1 _
1+                0, increment the result _
,                 0, Repeat that many times: _
  :1+s            0, Increment signum but keep the original value _
                  0, This is useful because we only want to _
                  0, decrement once in the 2 case _
  ,               0, If our previous signum value is 1: do this once _
    T+            0, Add signum value by -1 _
  _               0, End foreach loop _
_                 0, End foreach loop _

0, Implicit output the signum value left on the stack _
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer/language!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
_Ṡ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts \$a\$ on the left and \$b\$ on the right and yields \$a \lt = \gt b\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4c4F////1zX7r2sBAA)**

#### How?

```
_Ṡ - Link: a, b
_  - (a) subtract (b)
 Ṡ - sign -> -1, 0, or 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>25</s> 15 bytes

```lua
lt(a,b)-gt(a,b)
```

Same as Arnauld's JS solution. Unfortunately Verbose, throwing away the advantages of the langauge.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@nRCNRJ0lTNx1C////3/S/GQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
gV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z1Y&input=NSA0)

```sh
g   # sign of the difference of implicit first input and
 V  # second input
```

Comment: What does `V` do, then?

Comment: @Seggan This program transpiles to the JS `U.g(V)`, where U is the first input and V is the second

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.47 bytes

```
_za
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaL46sSISyowILFplzGECYA)

Sign of `a-b`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
-ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/fhzoX//0fHGxrrmBjF/o8CAA)

Same answer as many other esolangs.

#### Explanation

```
-     Subtract
 ṡ    Sign
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a<=>b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k60cbWLqn2f4FCWrShjmksF5iBYJnqGJrG/gcA)

(feels like cheating)

Comment: I suggest adding this to the [CW](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259275/95126) for languages with the exact ```<=>``` operator.

Comment: `->{_1<=>_2}` is one byte shorter.

Comment: @south ```->{_1<=>_2}``` doesn't seem to work when copy-pasted into TIO...

Comment: TIO uses an out-of-date ruby version. Implicit block parameters were added after 2.5.5.

Comment: `proc &:<=>` is 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 8 bytes

Does exactly the expected.

```
&compare
```

This is a built-in function that simply returns the expected result.

---

### Example:

#### Code-like

```
// Should output 1
echo &compare(2, 1);
```

#### Plain-English-like

```
// Should output -1
Show the result of calling &compare with the arguments 1, 2.
```

---

### Test code:

This shows test results in a nice pretty table.

```
// Test data - self-explanatory
// Example 5 shows an error, as an example
$tests = &json_decode(<<<JSON
[
    {"a": 0, "b": 1, "result": -1},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "result": -1},
    {"a": 2, "b": 1, "result": 1},
    {"a": 2, "b": 2, "result": 0},
    {"a": 3, "b": 2, "result": 0}
]
JSON);

// Make the table pretty
$settings = call !TABLE->getDefaultSettings();
$settings->classHeader = &str_concat($settings->classHeader, " table-dark");
$settings->classBodyCell = &str_concat(
    $settings->classBodyCell,
    " text-center"
);
$settings->classBodyFirstCol = &str_concat(
    $settings->classBodyFirstCol,
    " text-center table-dark"
);
$settings->classHeaderItems = &str_concat(
    $settings->classHeaderItems,
    " w-25"
);

// Create the table
$table = call !TABLE->create($settings);

call $table->setHeader(["", "A", "B", "Result"]);

each $test in $tests {
    // This is where the function runs
    $result = &compare($test['a'], $test['b']);
    
    call $table->addRow(
        &iff(
            $result == $test["result"],
            "✔️",
            &str_concat("❌ (", $test["result"], ")")
        ),
        $test['a'],
        $test['b'],
        $result
    );
}

call $table->show();
```

#### Result:

[image: Result of running the example]

This is an example of how the table will look like.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 15 bytes

```
f(a,b)=sgn(a-b)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m1hwumt2y3)

Answer (score 1):

## Binary-encoded Golfical, 27 bytes

Hexdump of binary encoding:

```
00 30 07 15 14 14 14 14 17 17 0c 01 14 14 14 17
00 01 02 01 1c 15 3b 4e 23 26 1d
```

Original program image:

[image]

Magnified 40x with RGB colors labeled:

[image]

Based on my answer [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103822/output-the-sign/259377#259377)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](https://common-lisp.net/), 28 bytes

```
(lambda(a b)(signum(- a b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX machine language, 2 instrs (8 bytes)

For `s64`:

```
00000000: 30000001 f8010000                    0¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

Disassembled:

```
    CMP $0,$0,$1        // x = x <=> y
    POP 1,0             // return x
```

For `u64`:

```
00000000: 32000001 f8010000                    2¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

Disassembled, the only change is the first instruction is now `CMPU`.

For `f64`:

```
00000000: 01000001 f8010000                    ¢¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

And this time the first instruction is `FCMP`.

All of these functions are excellent candidates for inlining.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 14 bytes

```
nns=!rlLfp2*,*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8vr9hWsSjHJ63ASEtH6/9/Cy4LAA)

Longer than I'd hoped, but I couldn't find a shorter way to do it given the instructions available...

```
nns             - read in two numbers, stash the second one away
   =!           - are they equal? invert result so "0" is set for equal
     rl         - reverse stack, recover the second number
       L        - do "less than" comparison
        fp      - delete the first number (it's still on the stack)
          2*,   - converts "0" to "-1" and "1" stays "1"
             *  - multiple by "are they equal?" val to get "0" as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 31 Bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(x:=a-b)and x/abs(x)
```

-7 Bytes from The Thonnu.

`abs(x)` gets the absolute value of `x` (think of it as scissors that can cut the `-` sign off numbers).

Comment: I would recommend using either [Try it online!](//tio.run) or [Attempt This Online!](//ato.pxeger.com) before submitting an answer. It allows you and others to test your program, and you can also copy the submission from there instead of writing it up yourself.

Comment: Also, [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqUTdJITEvRQNIa@onJhWDGf8LijLzSjTSNEx1jDU1uRA8UxSeuabmfwA), or [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKo8LKNlE3STMxL0WhQj8xqVijQvN/QVFmXolGmoapjrGmJheCZ4rCM9fU/A8A) in Python 3.8+

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 3 bytes

```
cmp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWi5NzCyCsmzZp-UUamQq2CgY6CiY6CiBeFpxXUJSZVwKUVdJRUFLIAmJdOyCRppGpo5ClCQQQMxYsgNAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 24 bytes

```
(compose'floor'signum'-)
```

This is the functional composition of functions `floor`, `signum` and `-`.

The `signum` function computes the sign and return the expected values, but for floating point values the result is also a float, either `-1.0`, `-0.0`, `+0.0` or `+1.0`. That's why the `floor` operation is used to convert the result back to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/Glan9/Gaia), 1 byte

```
C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#gaia)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṛ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWix_unL2kOCm5GMpfsNiUyxjCBAA)

Built-in. Inputs in reverse order, `b` then `a`. Requires \$\le 2.2.0\$, as this was changed in Thunno \$2.2.1\$.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
_ʂ
```

Same as most other answers: sign of `a-b`. Inputs in normal order, `a` then `b`. Works in all versions.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi-NPNS0pTkouhvIXLDblMoYwAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 7 bytes

```arturo
compare
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?59hUdU)

Builtin.

(In Arturo, `<=>` is the between operator. `5 <=> 1 10` would return `true`.)

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 33 bytes

```arturo
$[a b][(a>b)?->1->(a=b)?->0->0-1]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?fJStC6)

Non-builtin.

Arturo doesn't have a sign function or integer booleans, so I couldn't think of anything better than a nested ternary.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 9 bytes

```
[ - sgn ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVBQlFpSUllQlJlXopCdWpSXmqNgzcVlaqpgavY/WkFXoTg9TyH2f3JiTo6C3n8A)

Sign of difference. Factor has a `<=>` word, but it returns `+lt+`, `+eq+`, and `+gt+` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language) Assembly, 5 Bytes

```
I-IOT
```

I belive you had said that any negative or positive number works.

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), 40 bytes

```
=x=a'=b'!a}1,b,3}3,b}2,b,2`3!$|`2!-|`1>x
```

takes 2 inputs from STDIN.