# Comparator function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, comparison

Need to write a JS function compare(a,b) for numbers which return
1 when a > b, 0 when a == b, -1 when a < b.
Also following properties should hold:

1. compare(NaN, NaN) = 0
2. NaN is bigger than any other number, so compare(NaN, any) = 1 and compare(any, NaN) = -1.
3. compare(-0.0, 0.0) = -1 and compare(0.0, -0.0) = 1.
   Other numbers are ordered by default.

Other way to define: function should behave as Double.compare method in Java.

Comment: sounds like [Implement the \`<=>\` three-way comparison operator on numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/259255) but floating-point only.

Comment: @SuperStormer As far as I can tell the other challenge does not require handling of non-finite numbers which seems to be the main part of this challenge

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. As it stands, this challenge is lacking [an objective winning criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria). If this is actually a programming question, it is off-topic on this site and may be better received on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Include a [tag:code-golf] tag if you are seeking for golfing answers. Or you may be get help on Stack Overflow if you are asking general programming questions.

Comment: JavaScript (Node.js), 53 bytes: [`compare=(a,b)=>Math.sign(a-b||1/a-1/b||(b==b)-(a==a))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN02T83MLEotSbTUSdZI0be18E0sy9Ioz0_M0EnWTamoM9RN1DfWBDI0kW9skTV2NRFvbRE1NiOZbjC-T8_OK83NS9XLy0zWgJmkY6hhoanJhkzHAI2OIJqOkCwdK2PUY6RjjME3XWMeUZON0PfPSMvMySyp1YAxcppsTUkHIJMKO8Uv00wFiHOaDZHGHJKY-wvYZ6OjiMlAXHGuQGIclGwA)

Comment: @l4m2 `f=(a,b)=>(a>b)-(b>a)||+!a.at&&f([1/a],[1/b])` is 44 bytes; or 52 bytes with extra `compare=`

Comment: @tsh Same length JavaScript (Node.js), 52 bytes: [`compare=(a,b)=>Math.sign(a-b||1/a-1/b)|(b==b)-(a==a)`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN02S83MLEotSbTUSdZI0be18E0sy9Ioz0_M0EnWTamoM9RN1DfWTNGs0kmxtkzR1NRJtbRM1IXpvMb5Mzs8rzs9J1cvJT9eAGqRhqGOgqcmFTcYAj4whmoySLhwoYddjpGOMwzRdYx1Tko3T9cxLy8zLLKnUgTFwmW5OSAUhkwg7xi_RTweIcZgPksUdkpj6CNtnoKOLy0BdcKxBYhyWagA)

Comment: JavaScript, 51 bytes: `compare=(a,b)=>a>b|-(b>a)|(1/a>b|a!=a)-(1/b>a|b!=b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

*-5 bytes, thanks to l4m2*

```javascript
compare=(a,b)=>(a>b)-(b>a)||(1/a>1/b)-(1/b>1/a)+(b==b)-(a==a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN22T83MLEotSbTUSdZI0be00Eu2SNHU1kuwSNWtqNAz1E-0M9UECQBLIStTU1kiytQUJJNraJmpCDLnF-DI5P684PydVLyc_XQNqooahjoGmJhc2GQM8MoZoMkq6cKCEXY-RjjEO03SNdUxJNk7XMy8tMy-zpFIHxsBlujkhFYRMIuwYv0Q_HSDGYT5IFndIYuojbJ-Bji4uA3XBsQaJcVjyAQA)

### Explanation

```
compare=(a,b)=>
  (a>b)-(b>a)||        // compare values, return if non-zero
  (1/a>1/b)-(1/b>1/a)  // compare inverse values to check for -0<0
   +(b==b)-(a==a)      // compare equalities to check for NaN
```

Comment: `?x:` ==> `||`.